# ArcGIS Routing on Android with Network Analyst module

Tags: java, android, routes, arcgis

I am currently developing an Android App for navigation purposes. It is based on the ArcGIS Android API. I have an ArcGIS server (with network analyst module) with all the needed data running.

At the moment the App displays a map with the current position (point A) and has a search form, where you can search for a building (point B).

The next step would be to display a route from "point A" to "point B". Does anybody know if there is a way to do that natively with the Android API?

Also it would be possible to compute the routing information on a Java web service and then send it to the app, which only has to display it.

I cannot find any sample code on the ArcGIS resource page.

Comment: If you don't get the answer here, try http://gis.stackexchange.com